# Dask API for memory saving for matrix dot

Tags: python, numpy, memory, dask

I am using Dask for large-than-memory matrix multiplication. If I limit the memory to be 128MB, the program is killed when do 1000x1000 matrix dot. Whereas in-memory 1000x1000 matrix dot works perfectly. Could anyone give me some hints where I did wrong? Thank you very much!

```
import dask as dk
import tables
import numpy as np
import sys
from time import time
import math
import h5py

outpath = "/data/dottest/"
lenx = int(sys.argv[1])
leny = int(sys.argv[2])
numpart =int( math.sqrt(int(sys.argv[3])))

fname = "t{0:03d}_{1:03d}.h5".format(int(lenx),int(leny))

def writefile():
    h5f = h5py.File(fname, 'w')

    pres = np.random.random((lenx,leny))
    h5f.create_dataset('pressure',shape=pres.shape,chunks=(leny/numpart,lenx/numpart),dtype='f8',data=pres)

    lines = np.random.random((leny,lenx))
    h5f.create_dataset('lines',shape=lines.shape,chunks=(lenx/numpart,leny/numpart),dtype='f8',data=lines)

    h5f.close()

def dottest():
    import h5py
    import dask.array as da
    h5open2 = h5py.File(outpath+fname)

    print('numpart = ',numpart)

    d1=da.from_array(h5open2["/pressure"],chunks=(leny/numpart,lenx/numpart))
    d2=da.from_array(h5open2["/lines"],chunks=(leny/numpart,lenx/numpart))
    print d1 
    print d2

    t = d1.dot(d2)
    s = t.compute()

    print("dot finished")
    h5open2.close()

writefile()
dottest()
```

$echo 134217728 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/mygroup/memory.limit_in_bytes

$cgexec -g cpu,memory:mygroup python inmemory.py 1000 1000

0.0245869159698

$cgexec -g cpu,memory:mygroup python newdasktest.py 1000 1000 4

dask.array 'array, shape=(1000, 1000), dtype=float64, chunksize=(500, 500)'

dask.array 'array, shape=(1000, 1000), dtype=float64, chunksize=(500, 500)'

killed